# API for Natural Language Processing in Android

Tags: android, nlp

I am trying to make an Android application similar to the one on [this website](http://cleverbot.com/).

The thing is that I am pretty new to the field of Natural Language Processing. I do not wish to achieve much, just provide the user some interaction with the application, give him a feeling that he is indeed chatting with someone.

Basically, I would just capture the text entered by the user and send it over to the API and display the result retrieved from the API.
I came across http://opennlp.apache.org/ and http://gate.ac.uk/ but have NO idea how to implement them in my Android application.

**ANY** ideas/ suggestions/ help would indeed be great.

Thanks!

Comment: you can set up a server with one of these APIs and expose a webservice which the android apps can consume.

Comment: Nice idea! But to set up the server, I would need to buy server space on the public domain right ?

Comment: yes...but not right away...you can start developing by setting up a server on your local machine and can buy server+domain when you are done with all the coding and testing. also it does not cost much these days.

Comment: Are there no available API's or Web-services which would let me do this directly, without having me to go through the ordeal of getting my own server ?

Comment: @Swayam, have you had any luck with it after all? Which solution did you use? Was `http://dev.maluuba.com` free? Thank you in advance for your response!

Comment: Yes, but their sign up was crashing the last time I checked. :(